# apache 403 forbidden on OSX

Tags: apache, cgi

I can't get apache on one OSX system to allow permission to execute a CGI script. It works on a different OSX system and on an Ubuntu system. Here are the relevant directives from the apache config file:

```
User www
Group www
DocumentRoot "/opt/local/apache2/htdocs"
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/opt/local/apache2/cgi-bin"
<Directory "/opt/local/apache2/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Directory /opt/local/apache2/cgi-bin is owned by www and has permissions 755. But when I go to URL

```
localhost/cgi-bin/myCgiScript
```

I get a 403 error. I can view documents in the doc root location without getting a 403 error. I don't understand why the server has no permission to execute the CGI script.